# Passing writable store values from parent to child component via props in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm new to svelte and I'm trying to get a sense for best practices. I want to create a dynamic form component I can use throughout an app. Each instance of the form will have the same styling - but each form will be tied to different input values in the store, will have different submit logic, etc.

Here's a simple example (that doesn't work):

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
  import store from "./store";
  import Form from "./Form.svelte";

  const { inputValueA, inputValueB } = store;

  const handleSubmitA = () => {
    alert($inputValueA);
  };

  const handleSubmitB = () => {
    alert($inputValueB);
  };
</script>

<div>
  <Form
    inputValue={$inputValueA}
    labelText="form input a"
    handleSubmit={handleSubmitA}
  />
  <Form
    inputValue={$inputValueB}
    labelText="form input b"
    handleSubmit={handleSubmitB}
  />
</div>
```

**Form.svelte**

```
<script>
  export let handleSubmit = () => null;
  export let inputValue = "";
  export let labelText = "";
</script>

<form>
  <label for="input">{labelText}</label>
  <input id="input" type="text" value={inputValue} />
  <button on:click|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>submit</button>
</form>
```

This example doesn't work, I don't believe the inputValue prop is bound to the text input correctly. Any folks out there with svelte experience willing to share how you'd approach this?

Here's a sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-form-component-ujnwki

Let me know what you suggest! Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what is exactly is your question but here is the fix for your example to make it work:

you have to `bind` the value to your component to be able to change it form the child

```
bind:inputValue={$inputValueA}
```

and `bind` the value to the input itself to make its value reactive

```
bind:value={inputValue}
```